# Pinching geometry when using subdivision modifier

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects, edit-mode

This is my first time trying to make an anime girl's head.
[image]

Everything was fine until I add a Subdivision Surface modifier and the nose looks weird, I don't know how to fix it.
[image]

Is there any solutions to this?
Here's the file: [image]

Comment: can you attach your blend file at https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: it can be inverted normals, overlapping vertices, inner face...

Comment: yes, I just edited the post with the file

Comment: @BaoHa as mentioned by moonboots it indeed is inverted normals. Go `tab` into *Edit Mode* and press `A` to select all faces then press `Shift`+`N`. Now you can apply your subdivision surf modifier nicely.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie no, it didn't work

Comment: ofcourse it will work. you just did it incorrectly :) give me a moment i will add it as answer with attached fixed file.

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 0):

Your face normals are inverted. You can see the faces in blue when they are correctly pointing outwards when you check *Face Orientation* under *Overlays*. Go <kbd>tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>3</kbd> to switch to *Face Select* mode then press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all faces.

[image]

Then go to *Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside* or press the shortcut
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

[image]

Now the face normals are blue and correct and you can add the *Subdivision Surface* modifier

[image]

[image]